# PCM270xC USB audio DAC, power modes and THD

Tags: audio, dac

I am designing a USB DAC for headphone use, and planing to use a TI PCM270xC IC.
There are two power modes: (USB) bus powered, and self powered.
What I'm trying to understand is how does the power choice influence the THD characteristics.
This is the info provided on the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm2704c.pdf):

[image: datasheet THD info]

Does this mean that the THD is always lower when Self-Powered? If so why is the displayed RL value lower?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just generic marketing talk. The actual data is later on page 9 of the datasheet, under Dynamic Performance. If the load is 32 ohm headphones, there is no difference. If the load is larger than 10kohms like a line input of an amplifier, the self-powered mode does have lower THD than bus-powered mode.

Comment: I believe the actual difference is between 5V and 3.3V operation.  The chip probably doesn't care where the power is coming from.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems that the best course of action would be to drive a high input impedance amp with this IC and then connect the headphones?